# How to implement a horizontal moving joystick, Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

How to implement a horizontal moving joystick, that can be moved from left to right.
The controller should return back to its initial position (center) on release,
Also, I should be able to fetch the values live as the controller moves left or right.
The range of values is from 1 (extreme left) to 100 (extreme right). It will be helpful if I could change the range of values, just like a seek bar.
Any reference or links while be helpful. Thanks.

The joystick view is below,

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this kind of large, open-ended question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: you will have to implement touch handling for your view